# Protractor get suite name

Tags: protractor

```
protractor Conf.js --suite AppSuite --params.env staging
```

I can get environment name using:

```
browser.params.env
```

How can I get suite name?

```
browser.suite
```

won't work.

Comment: assuming you are using nodejs, you could use `__filename` which will give you the filepath, and then parse it to get the current file you are in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [getProcessedConfig](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorBrowser.prototype.getProcessedConfig) as below:

```
browser.getProcessedConfig().then(function(config) {
    console.log('suite: ' + config.suite)
});
```